# AttributeError: module 'imp' has no attribute 'fit_transform' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv('palmerpenguins.csv')
dfc = df.copy()  # we keep a copy in case we need the original data set

from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
encode = LabelEncoder()
impute = KNNImputer()

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sca = MinMaxScaler()
df_sca = pd.DataFrame(sca.fit_transform(df),columns=dfc.columns)
df_sca.head()

**new_df = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df_sca), columns=dfc.columns)**
new_df.isnull().sum()
```

When I execute this code segment in Jupyter Notebook, the error occurred  **in second line from the bottom of the code**, like this.

```
AttributeError: module 'imp' has no attribute 'fit_transform'
```

What is the solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Always include the traceback in questions about exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The name `imp` is not defined. Maybe you simply meant `impute.fit_transform(df_sca)`?

Anyway, I would recommend using a [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) object to concatenate multiple operations on your data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).